# top 5 records in mongodb with yiimongodbsuite

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

How to get the top 5 document in mongodb with yiimongodbsuite.I already used this

```
    $cursor = $model::model()->getCollection()->find($criteria->getConditions());
    if($criteria->getSort() !== null)
        $cursor->sort($criteria->getSort());
    if($criteria->getOffset() !== null)
        $cursor->skip($criteria->getOffset());
    if($criteria->getSelect())
        $cursor->fields($criteria->getSelect(true));
    $cursor->limit(5);
    return location::$model->populateRecord($cursor->getNext());
```

but I am getting only one document.

Comment: What is in $criteria??

Comment: Because you fetch one record of the cursor. Use `EMongoDocumentDataProvider`.

Comment: @PeterM doesn't find return a cursor? EMongodataProvider is used when explicitly inited aint it?

Comment: Thanks for response Peter here is the criteria
$criteria = new EMongoCriteria;

Comment: @Sammaye last line populates one record: `$model->populateRecord($cursor->getNext());`

Comment: @PeterM yeah that's prolly it